# parsing regular expression for sub and gsub in r

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am having trouble understanding what the regular expressions in the following lines of code mean.

```
author = "10_1 A Kumar; Ahmed Hemani ; Johnny &Ouml;berg<"

# after some experiment, it looks like this line captures whatever is in
# front of the underscore.
authodid =  sub("_.*","",author)

# this line extracts the number after the underscore, but I don't know 
# how this is achieved
paperno <- sub(".*_(\\w*)\\s.*", "\\1", author)

# this line extracts the string after the numbers
# I also have no idea how this is achieved through the code
coauthor <- gsub("<","",sub("^.*?\\s","", author))
```

I have read on the web that the first argument is the pattern, second is the replacement, and the third is the object to operate on. I also saw a few post on SO and learned that `\\w` means the a word and `\\s` is a space.

However, a few things are still unclear. `\\w` means word, does it mean the next word? If not, how should I interpret it? I learned that `^` matches the start of the string, but what about the period after `^`?

More importantly, what is the interpretation of `_.*` What about `.*_` How about `^.*?\\s`? How should I read them?

Thanks!

Comment: type those things in here https://regex101.com

Comment: @rawr Which flavor should I choose? It seems like all of them show an error.

Comment: [pcre should be fine](https://regex101.com/r/sIb7Ql/1), I dont get an error, maybe you do because of the double \ which are not needed when you use this website

Comment: @rawr absolutely marvelous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. There is quite a number of questions. First things first.

`sub("_.*","",author)` looks for `_` and everything else after that. So in your case `_.*` corresponds to  `_1 A Kumar; Ahmed Hemani ; Johnny &Ouml;berg<`. Function `sub` relapse it with '' (so, De facto it deletes it), so you end up with `10`.

`sub(".*_(\\w*)\\s.*", "\\1", author)` is more tricky (with out any reason). It does not extract anything. If you replace the code to `sub(".*_(\\w*)\\s.*", "222", author)` the result would be `222` (instead of `1`). So whatever you put in the second argument you will get as a result. Why it so? Well, because `".*_(\\w*)\\s.*"` corresponds to entire string, namely: `.*_` corresponds to `10_`; `(\\w*)` corresponds to `1` and finally `\\s.*` means space and everything after it (so, the rest of the string).

`gsub("<","",sub("^.*?\\s","", author))` there are two functions. The first one `sub("^.*?\\s","", author)`. It looks everything from the beginning to space. So `^.*?\\s` stands for `10_1` and delete it. So, you end up with `A Kumar; Ahmed Hemani ; Johnny &Ouml;berg<`. And the second one deletes '<' from all over the place.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Is the following correct: `_.*` looks for everything after `_` and does operation on it, `.*_` looks for everything before `_` and does operation on it, and `^.*?` looks from the beginning until it finds something specified (in my case, `\\s`, a space) and does operation on that?

Comment: @what Short answer is yes.